# Socket never stop searching for SocketServer

Tags: java, sockets, search, networking, serversocket

Ok so my question is really simple as I have it I pretty much have a server and a client program, however I don't want my server to have to be on for client to run, so I want to have it so the client never stops searching for server and all I have to do is turn server on, does anyone know how I'd do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a while loop. Keep in mind that this will stall your program until it connects, so you should probably do this on a separate thread.

```
boolean done = false;
while (!done) {
    try {
        // Socket initialization code
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (!e.getMessage().equals(/* Error code for unable to find server */) {
            done = true;
    }
}
```